# How to decompress a zip archive which has sub directories?

Tags: java, android

Say I have a zip file `MyZipFile.zip` which contains (1) a file `MyFile.txt` and (2) a folder `MyFolder` which contains a file `MyFileInMyFolder.txt`, i.e. something as follows:

> `MyZipFile.zip`
>      |-> `MyFile.txt`
>      |-> `MyFolder`
>             |-> `MyFileInMyFolder.txt`

I want to decompress this zip archive. The most common code sample I have been able to find searching online uses the `ZipInputStream` class somewhat like the code pasted at the bottom of this question. The problem with this however, using the example above, is that it will create `MyFolder` but will not decompress the contents of `MyFolder`. Anyone know whether it is possible to decompress the contents of a folder in a zip archive using `ZipInputStream` or by any other means?

```
public static boolean unzip(File sourceZipFile, File targetFolder)
{
 // pre-stuff

 ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceZipFile));
 ZipEntry zipEntry = null;

 while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null)
 {
  File zipEntryFile = new File(targetFolder, zipEntry.getName());

  if (zipEntry.isDirectory())
  {
   if (!zipEntryFile.exists() && !zipEntryFile.mkdirs())
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
   FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(zipEntryFile);

   byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
   int count;

   while ((count = zipInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count); 

   fileOutputStream.flush();
   fileOutputStream.close();
   zipInputStream.closeEntry();
  }
 }

 zipInputStream.close();

 // post-stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ZipInputStream zis = null;
try {

    zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
    ZipEntry entry;

    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

        // Create a file on HDD in the destinationPath directory
        // destinationPath is a "root" folder, where you want to extract your ZIP file
        File entryFile = new File(destinationPath, entry.getName());
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {

            if (entryFile.exists()) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Directory {0} already exists!", entryFile);
            } else {
                entryFile.mkdirs();
            }

        } else {

            // Make sure all folders exists (they should, but the safer, the better ;-))
            if (entryFile.getParentFile() != null && !entryFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
                entryFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }

            // Create file on disk...
            if (!entryFile.exists()) {
                entryFile.createNewFile();
            }

            // and rewrite data from stream
            OutputStream os = null;
            try {
                os = new FileOutputStream(entryFile);
                IOUtils.copy(zis, os);
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);
            }
        }
    }
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(zis);
}
```

Note, that it uses [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to handle stream copying / closing.

Comment: Thanks for the response npe. Turns out in fact my code was working. Problem was that the names of the files in my sub folder (within the zip archive) started with a dot (i.e. `.MyFile.txt`) and though the code runs ok (no exceptions etc), these files are not actually to be found in the decompressed target folder. I'm just being careful now not to have my file names start with a dot. I did include the safety check you have of checking that the `entryFile` parent directory exists (and creating it if not) so thanks for that.